# How do I query a list of users?

Tags: typeorm

If I want to query a list of users, I want to dynamically pass in the parameters, for example, can only query according to username, or according to the combination of username and userType conditions to query, I do not know how to use typeORm to write

Comment: Please provide an example or the structure of your ```@Entity()```(s)

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is find options. Link to official documentation: [TypeORM - Find Options](https://typeorm.io/#/find-options)

```
repository.findOne(id?: string | number | Date | ObjectID, options?: FindOneOptions<Entity>): Promise<Entity | undefined>;
```

findOne function takes in two parameters. First one defines logic to how you want the record to find, by id or its column value. Second parameter lets you fetch the relations if you have any with the specific entity.

Comment: I mean, for example, a user table, which contains fields such as username, email,nickaname, and so on. Now, when I query the data in this table, I can query the data based on the three conditions at the same time, or I can query the data based on one or both conditions. How to write this using TypeORm, is to query according to different conditions, can you do it?

Comment: Try the following query, userRepository.find({"name": "Tom", "email": "tom@mail.com"}, ["role"]) This will return all the records matching the name and email. This operation should be defined in service layer class where controller or other part of your application consumes it where you can dynamically provide the conditions on which repository should look for records.